# Getting No Such Element Exception Reading in file

Tags: java, text-files, nosuchelementexception

I'm reviewing practice assignments working up to my final and one thing my professor had us do was create and use a student class. Below I provided my code and what's in the text file I'm reading from.

```
    String inputFileName = "quizScore.txt";
    File inputFile = new File(inputFileName); 
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(inputFile);
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    //Skip first two lines 
    fileIn.nextLine();
    fileIn.nextLine();

    int i =0;

    while (fileIn.hasNextLine()){
         //skip first number
        fileIn.nextInt();

        //Add student with quiz score
        String newStudent = fileIn.next();
        int quizScore = fileIn.nextInt();

        Student student = new Student(newStudent); 
        students.add(student);

        //Add quiz score 
        student.addQuiz(quizScore);
        i++;
    }


    Skip this line
    And this line
    1   Michael 285
    2   Christopher 236 
    3   Joshua  230 
    4   Brandon 208 
    5   Jacob   202 
    6   Daniel  196 
    7   Matthew 193 
    8   Anthony 188 
    9   Andrew  172 
    10  Joseph  171
```

I wrote the class but when I try to implement the class its says `NoSuchElementException` in the `while` loop for the `fileIn.nextInt()`; that's suppose to skip the line number. I don't know why it's giving me that exception. If I do a print statement to see if there is an int there is. Which is why I'm confused I get an error.

Comment: Can you post the file content.  At least first 5 lines or so

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this site so I didn't know how. I just tried pasting in the contents below my code.

Comment: you should be able to edit the question and paste the content.

Answer (score 1):

Change the condition of the while loop to `fileIn.hasNextInt()`. That way, if your file has a new line at the end, your loop will stop when the next line does not start with an integer.

Also you don't seem to be using the value of your `i` variable anywhere. You may want to get rid of it, unused variables are never a good idea.

Comment: Thank you that worked for me! It fixed my only issue I have.